# Perl lib version (5.10.1) doesn't match executable version (v5.18.4)

Tags: linux, perl

I have perl 5.18.4 installed in my linux box, i want to install 5.10.1 also, so i tried to install perl-5.10.1 making a directory 5.10 in my home directory and ran

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/D/DA/DAPM/perl-5.10.1.tar.gz
```

and after that tried

```
tar zxvf perl-5.10.1.tar.gz
cd perl-5.10.1
sh Configure -des -Dcc=gcc -Dusethreads -Uuselargefiles -Duse64bitall -  Duse64bitint -Duseshrplib -Dusemultiplicity -Duseposix -Dd_sigaction –Duseperlio
make 
make test
make install
```

and then after running

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

i got this error

```
perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Cwd/Cwd.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Gthr_key_ptr
```

Googling, someone suggested to reinstall Cwd.so, so i downloaded PathTools-3.47.tar.gz which has Cwd.so and tried to install it running Makefile.PL inside PathTools, then i got this error

```
Perl lib version (5.10.1) doesn't match executable version (v5.18.4) at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1//x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Config.pm line 50.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1/ExtUtils/MakeMaker/Config.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1/ExtUtils/MakeMaker/Config.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at Makefile.PL line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 11.
```

Answer (score 2):

> sh Configure -des ...

Since you did not specify an installation path for your new Perl it uses the default path and thus you will probably end up with a mix of libraries, that is 5.10 and 5.18 mixed up.

Make it easy for yourself by simply using [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/).

Comment: Even while installing perlbrew i am getting the same error "Perl lib version (5.10.1) doesn't match executable version (v5.18.4) at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1//x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Config.pm line 50.
Compilation failed in require at perlbrew-32072 line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at perlbrew-32072 line 3."

Comment: I don't know what your are actually doing, but make sure you cleanly removed the previous installation attempt (the one without perlbrew), have no PERLLIB or PERL5LIB environments left from previous experiments, have a working installation of your original perl and switch between perl installations only with perlbrew.